# Setting padding and margin to 0 doesn´t work

Tags: qt, stylesheet, margin, padding, qtstylesheets

It´s just a container and i want to put widgets inside and hide them and show them. I don´t want it to have any margins or paddings, and it will be invisible (no border, no background)

I set the QWidget#container  to margin:0px, padding:0px through a stylesheet.
And setObjectName("container") to all the widgets that contain.

Nothing happens. But setting a background color works, so it is executed.

In which cases does this happen?
How to fix this?

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-customizing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QWidget does not support [box model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model), so it does not understand padding/margin CSS directives. Use QFrame as container. To see which widgets support box model take a look at [list of stylable widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-stylable-widgets)

Comment: Nope. Doesn´t work. I though it was very obvious. But doesn´t work. I tried to set the margins to 50px, and works (so the stylesheet works), but when i set it to 0, i see space between the widgets inside and the border. So i think something inside has margins... a simple QLabel ? a Spinbox?. Do they have margins?

Comment: Remember that layout settings may override this. Set contents margins to 0 first

Comment: Yeah! I came to say that setting through code  setMargin(0)  to the layout inside works... What do you mean by contents margins?. I though setting margin to 0 would work though the stylesheet. So you tell me to add using code setting all layout margins to 0 ? I don´t understand completely, but thanks!.

Comment: I set contentmargins to the layouts to (0,0,0,0). That worked.
But then, everything where i put a layout overrides what the stylesheet says, then?. So saying anything about the margins or padidngs is not worth it through the stylesheet?

Comment: I've made project with whole ui based on CSS and had no problem with margins/padding. I used QFrames and layouts with content margins set to 0. I don't know what more I can say to you, as clearly you don't understand how it works and you're not trying to provide a code sample that can reproduce your problem. You didn't even say what version of Qt and what platform you're using

Comment: Sorry about that. QT 4.7, Windows 32, 64 and Mac.  So you ALWAYS have to put content margins to 0 in every layout based QFrame?

Comment: And where is your problem occuring? On all platforms? I remember that to some css directives take effect I had to set borders: 0 also

Comment: So. To finish this:  If you have a widget with BoxModel available with a layout, the stylesheet margin and padding doesn´t work. So you have to add setContentMargins to 0 or whatever you like. Apart from this, do the margins and paddings work? or should i change them by hand in code?

Comment: But there's nothing to show!. It works now. I just set content margins to 0 and it works. I put nothing on the styletheet. Can i use padding and margin apart from fixing that?

Comment: The solution was to use  setSpacing(0). That, together with setContentsMargin(0,0,0,0) creates raw, no margin / padding layout. Then you can add ONLY margins. Not padding...

Answer (score 2):

Given there was no concise answer I'll sum up the above:

To create a container with no margins and padding, instead of `QWidget`, use `QFrame`, and set a layout on it. Then set the spacing to 0 and set the content margins to 0 as well on the layout. Using a stylesheet setting padding/margin to 0 will have no effect.

Code:

```
QFrame* containerFrame = new QFrame();
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->setSpacing(0);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
// add some widgets to the layout
containerFrame->setLayout(layout);
```